# Changes I make to the files in my website folder get automatically reverted when I run the server

Tags: html, css, jekyll, web-hosting

I am using Jekyll to make a personal website. I downloaded a Bootstrap template and started changing details around. I changed the config.yml file as well as the index.html file.

When I write `bundle exec jekyll serve` into the command line, the server starts running and I can see a demo of what my website will look like once it is being hosted online.

The changes I made to the config.yml file persist, but those I made to the index.html file **do not**. When I look at the index.html file, every single change I made is reverted back to the original. It's almost like the index.html gets regenerated to a default version whenever I run the server.

The same thing happens when I try to change the default image files within the project. The new images that I placed in the *img* folder get deleted and the old ones that I removed get regenerated.

I googled around but found no helpful answer (deleting my browser cache does not solve the issue). Anyone know what's going on?

**Edit:** I should add a piece of information that may be the cause of this issue. I have two index.html files in my website. One of them is in the root folder and it simply redirects to "layout: default". The other one is in the _site folder. The latter is the one I tried to change to no avail.

Default file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    {% include head.html %}
    <body id="page-top" class="index">
      {% include nav.html %}
      {% include header.html %}
      {% include portfolio_grid.html %}
      {% include about.html %}

      {% if site.contact == "static" %}
      {% include contact_static.html %}
      {% elsif site.contact == "disqus" %}
      {% include contact_disqus.html %}
      {% else %}
      {% include contact.html %}
      {% endif %}

      {% include footer.html %}
      {% include modals.html %}
      {% include js.html %}
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `jekyll serve` or `jekyll build` is executed, the default behaviour is to regenerate all your site into the `_site` folder.

To make changes to your index.html root file, you need to edit the one **outside** the `_site` folder (probably named `/index.md` or /index.html`) because the content of`_site` are built in each run.

Comment: I had a feeling. Your explanation makes sense but I do want to ask you a follow up question: would the solution be simply to replace the index.html file with the index.html file in the _site directory?

Comment: Reason why I am asking is because the root index.html has only one line in it, and I don’t see a way to change my landing page just by changing that file alone.

Comment: No, `/_site/index.html` is the result of Jekyll processing `/index.md` or `/index.html`, that is what a static generator does.

Comment: You need to understand the different pieces involved in the root index.html so you know where to edit the file, it could be that you need to edit a layout or an include.